# Pass list members to one variable in a python function

Tags: python, list

I see a python function (extract) in a library like:

```
def print_len(list_members):
    my_list = [list_members]
    print(len(my_list))
```

I want to call the function with 2 or more list members and expect the result is more than 1. For example,

```
a = "one, two"
print_len(a)

a = "one", "two"
print_len(a)

a = ["one", "two"]
print_len(a)
```

But the results of all trials are 1. How can I call this function to get a result that is more than 1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. `list_members` is already a list, there is no point in putting it inside another list. Why not just `print(len(list_members))`?

Comment: You can't get a different output than "1" from that function. (Unless you monkeypatch `len`, I suppose...)

Comment: @DanielRoseman The function is in a library, and the code I showed is just a small part of the whole function that I am interested in. I import the library in my script, so I cannot change the function myself.

Comment: Well, the version of the function you showed will *always* return 1. If you want help with the real functionality, you should post the real code.

Comment: Well, you code wrap `print_len` into another function that adds a random int to the result, so you'll get "a result that is more than 1".  But really, if that's part of a lib, then either you took this part totally out of context so it's meaningless or this lib is completely broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print_len` function doesn't do what you think it does:

```
def print_len(list_members):
    my_list = [list_members]
    print(len(my_list))
```

This takes a parameter `list_members`. Let's say the value of that is your last example `["one", "two"]`. So, the length of `list_members` is 2 which is what you are expecting.

But then your code does

```
    my_list = [list_members]
```

so `my_list` looks like this: `[["one", "two"]]`  ... in other words, a list of *one* element. That element itself has 2 elements. But your code is taking the length of the outer list, which will always be 1. Print `len(list_members)` instead.

Comment: The code in the function is in a library that I imported in my script. I ask the question to see if there are some good ways to call and use the function without changing the function itself.

Comment: That function will always print `1`. No matter what you pass the function. It creates a list of length `1` and then prints its length. The only way that I can think of to get the function to report the length of the data is to call it like this: `print_len(*a)`. Then if `a` has one element it will print `1` and if it has more, the TypeError message will tell you how many, for example `TypeError: print_len() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. But I think you were looking for something a little more elegant.